# Playing Crusader Kings II at very high resolution

Tags: macos, crusader-kings-2

I've noticed that in Crusader Kings II you can select the 5K Retina resolution: 5120x2880. I did, and the game resolution itself was correctly set… but the interfaces were just downscaled. That is, they just had the same amount of pixels, which means that on such a high resolution, they were usually smaller than the ball of my trackball.

Searching around, I've found many mods who claim to enlarge the fonts, but do not actually work. And anyway I do not need to just change the fonts, I'd like all the interfaces to get bigger…

I guess the answer is "just no, lower the resolution", but maybe here someone comes up with a more creative and effective answer?

Comment: Which OS are you playing on ?

Comment: @Ealhad OS X ["Retina" should have been a hint ;)]

Comment: Right. Though not being a Mac user, "Retina" didn't really hit me ;)

Comment: In practice people use the term "retina" to refer to all sorts of non-Apple high DPI displays, so it's not much of a hint.

Comment: @Lohoris Maybe some more actual Mac users will see the question, that way.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long standing issue with CK2 and related games. Paradox is too lazy to fix it, however there are several mods that somewhat mitigate the problem, for example this one
https://steamcommunity.com/app/203770/discussions/0/846964364055605789/

While it probably won't let you do a 5k resolution, it would still be a huge improvement